# In Swift, use a SQL query with an apostrophe

Tags: sql, swift

I have a user who is breaking my otherwise-working code, and I assume it's because his name has an apostrophe.  I've tried escaping it using a double apostrophe and a backslash but I keep getting `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`.

```
    let querySQL = "SELECT name from member_data ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1" 
    rightAnswer = memberDatabase!.executeQuery(querySQL, withArgumentsInArray: nil)
    rightAnswer!.next()
    correctName = rightAnswer!.stringForColumn("name")!
    println("Correct answer is \(correctName)") 
      //prints as Optional("Sam O\'Neal")
    let sanitizedName = correctName?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("'", withString: "\'")   
      //tried many combinations of this
    let wrongAnswerSQLQuery = "SELECT name from member_data where name is not '\(sanitizedName)' LIMIT 3"
    let wrongAnswersResultSet:FMResultSet = memberDatabase!.executeQuery(wrongAnswerSQLQuery, withArgumentsInArray: nil)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three issues:

1. You are using C-style escapes in your SQL. The [SQLite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html) says

   > A string constant is formed by enclosing the string in single quotes ('). A single quote within the string can be encoded by putting two single quotes in a row - as in Pascal. C-style escapes using the backslash character are not supported because they are not standard SQL.

   So replace `'` characters with `''`:

   ```
   let sanitizedName = correctName?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("'", withString: "''")
   ```
2. Your `sanitizedName` is optional, so you have to unwrap it or else it will appear as `Optional(...)`:

   ```
   let wrongAnswerSQLQuery = "SELECT name from member_data where name is not '\(sanitizedName!)' LIMIT 3"
   ```
3. Even better, you should cut the Gordian knot, and not build SQL statement with string values like this at all.

   Instead, you should use the `?` placeholders in your SQL and then pass the `correctName` in the `withArgumentsInArray`. Then you don't have to worry about doing any of this "sanitizing" at all:

   ```
   let wrongAnswerSQLQuery = "SELECT name from member_data where name is not ? LIMIT 3"
   let wrongAnswersResultSet = memberDatabase!.executeQuery(wrongAnswerSQLQuery, withArgumentsInArray: [correctName!])
   ```

Comment: Ah, perfect!  For what it's worth, I did try doubling up the apostrophe and was unsuccessful (in case other people are trying).  The third solution is clearly the best--thanks!

Comment: Yeah, you have to do _both_ the doubling and the unwrapping of the optional, if you go that route. But like you said, the approach using the `?` placeholders is best.